# Importing logo from Photoshop to Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, logo, eps

I'm not an expert with these tools at all, so my question might be stupid and the terms totally wrong.

**How do I get a logo from Photoshop to Illustrator so as the quality remains still good and sharp?**

I'm using the latest version of InDesign CC. I'm wondering why imported images look so bad, even when "Display Performance" is set to High Quality Display.

It looks OK within Photoshop but when I transfer it to Illustrator, it gets worse. Both documents' resolutions are set at 300 DPI. Should I convert them to 600 DPI or something like that? Should I import it as an image or Photoshop file? What would be the best way?

I believe that if an image is the right size and DPI within Photoshop and no scaling would occur, the image should be the same after importing it to Illustrator?

I'm not sure how the logo (PSD file with layers) is created with Photoshop, but I also have an EPS vector file that contains the edges of the logo.

> The logo within Photoshop is created using this vector file, then some Photoshop effects are applied to it.

Is it possible to use any vector graphics within Photoshop or it is just bitmap always? If that's possible, then hopefully those edges could still be vectors. Is there any Photoshop EPS format or something like that?

Anyway if the *edges **+** effects* are at right resolution/DPI and result is looking good within Photoshop, I believe I should get that to Illustrator without quality loss if scaling is not needed.

Hopefully this is not totally confusing :D

Comment: Why do you need to open it in Illustrator? From what you say, it sounds like your logo is raster, with photoshop effects. Only way to have it looking exactly the same in AI would be to completely re-draw it.

Comment: This is CD album cover and layout should be done at Illustrator probably.

Answer (score 1):

If your logo is made up of **all shapes and line** then you don't need to do anything you can always increase the size of your images without loosing the quality. You can change the **resolution, Width/height without loss of quality** and you also do not need to transform your logo into vector format.

I have never never created any image more that 300 Resolution in my entire career because there is no need. The printer that print the image at 300 resolution will give you the same result at 600 and will consume more ink. Although the resolution of 300 is also a very high number, Today, many printers can print very Good images in between 72 & 96 resolution its also depend on the type of material and USES(like for printing banners, posters, brochures etc).

If you want to use your logo for web then 72 resolution is Enough (Concentrate mainly on image sizes)

but if you PSD is all raster then you have to recreate your logo in Illustrator. there is no short-cut for that.

Comment: This would be ok if the logo is for a personal project, but if you are delivering it to a client you need to do so in a scalable format, so it can be re-used in different contexts.

Comment: Yes @Yisela but you can also scale your object in photoshop it They are all shapes and line then you don't need to convert it to vector format either if its  for personal use or for client. I have mentioned it in my answer.

Comment: Alright, but an .eps output would be ideal in that case (software-independent). And for web, you can't do 72 ppi anymore, because of retina screens. It needs to be at least double the size. All issues that are solved by delivering a logo in a scalable format.

Comment: So, Illustrator cannot import jpg/png image file without losing quality even if no scaling of any kind would occur? Can it really be so.

Comment: And now I finally found out that I was talking about Indesign. So there is Illustrator vector logo that is imported to Photoshop added some effects there and then transferred to InDesign. Sorry!

Comment: @Yisela as Rishab explained, photoshop can deliver scalable format. What would be 'ideal' for a client would differ per project.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop work with pixels and illustrator work with vectors so its impossible import the logo with photoshop effects and convert them to vector. 
If you redesign your logo in illustrator you can aply the same effects you use in photoshop, and if you need to use your logo in web you can also export your logo to svg then you don´t lose quality. 
You can send me the files for tiagofidalgo.adobecc@gmail.com and i can help you if you want.

Answer (score 0):

SFP

Indesign 'previews' bitmap images from Photoshop and here lies your answer. The programme is intended for layout, text and publishing not image editing. Be assured that the original resolution of your file will remain the same within the Indesign document, even if the preview looks a little shaky at certain magnifications. Still, its worth ensuring you do the following for print:

- Set the image at 300 dpi and CMYK format in Photoshop
- Save as an EPS file with a preview (check the button in the save settings)
- New Indesign document set to the 'real' size of your end product e.g. 297 x 210 mm for an A4 portrait flyer (height measurement always comes first with the printer)
- Make sure the Indesign colour profile is set to CMYK (or the one specified by your printer) to avoid colour shift
  Note: if your image is RGB at the moment change it in Photoshop to CMYK and adjust colour as required.

As to why Indesign does this, there could be several reasons. You've found the 'high' display setting in preferences (good) but this can be overridden at object level in the layout. Does your image include a preview to start with? Do you have a decent graphics card / RAM on your system? I have found on CS3, CS5 and CS6 that if I am working on a MacBook with Photoshop open, Indesign preview images will have reduced quality particularly if I manipulate them. If I close Photoshop they immediately go high resolution (without me doing anything) which leads me to believe that its a VRAM / RAM issue i.e. the Mac cannot cope with having the file at high resolution in Indesign and Photoshop at the same time.

For this latter reason, I generally work on a Mac tower with a 1 GB graphics card. If I am on the Macbook I do my image edits first, close Photoshop and them work in Indesign.

Best of luck with it.